What is the invertible elements of $R$ where $R= \mathbb Z[x] / (1+x+x^2)$?
What is the invertible elements of $R$ where $R= \mathbb Z[x] / (1+x+x^2)$?
The quotient basically means that we are taking all polynomials in $\mathbb Z[x]$ under the modulo $1+x+x^2$. That is, the terms that are multiple of $(1+x+x^2)$ will be zero i.e. each element that are in the same class with $(1+x+x^2)$ is going to be $0$.
In this example, I managed to write  structure of the quotient ring $$\mathbb Z[x] / (4,2x,x^2)=\{ \overline{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2}:a_0=0,1,2,3;a_1=0,1 \}$$
However, I couldn't even write the structure of $\mathbb Z[x] / (1+x+x^2)$ as above. And how can I find $(\mathbb Z[x] / (1+x+x^2))^*?$

The Eisenstein units are  $,\pm x^i,\ \ i< 3,,$  cf. linked dupes. $\ \ $

The only invertible elements are:
$$\{\pm1, \, \pm x, \, \pm(1+x)\}.$$
$\textbf{Proof:}$
Let $I =\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle$.  Any element of $R$ can be written as $ax+b+I$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers (because one can apply division algorithm to division by the monic polynomial $x^2+x+1$).
Now suppose $ax+b+I$ is a unit in $R$. Then for some $cx+d+I$ in $R$ we would have
$$(ax+b)(cx+d)+I =1+I.$$
This implies that
$$(ax+b)(cx+d)-1\in I.$$
That is $x^2+x+1$ divides $acx^2+(ad+bc)x+bd$. That is
$$acx^2+(ad+bc)x+bd-1 = (x^2+x+1)f(x),$$
where $f(x)$ must be a non zero constant. Say $f(x)=k$.
Now, we have
$$ ac=k; ad+bc=k; bd-1=k.$$
Suppose $a=0$. Then $k=0$ and $bd=1$. Thus both $b$ and $d$ are non zeroes. Also, $bc=0$ implying that $c=0$. Thus, we have $b=d=\pm1$. Clearly, in this case $ax+b+I=cx+d+I=\pm1+I$ and $\pm1+I$ are both units.
Suppose $b=0$. Then, $bd-1=k$ implies $k=-1$. Moreover $ad=-1$ and $ac=-1$. These two imply that, $ad-ac=0$. As $a$ cannot be zero, we must have that $c=d$. Also, as $ac=-1$, the only integers which satisfy these are $a=1, c=-1$ or $a=-1, c=1$. Thsu the units that we get in this situation are:

Taking $a=1$ and $c=d=-1$ Units are: $x, -1-x$.
Taking $a=-1$ and $c=d=1$ units are: $-x, 1+x$.

Now, suppose both $a$ and $b$ are non zero. Then from the relations we have listed down, we can arrive at
$$(k+1)\frac{a}{b}+k\frac{b}{a}=k.$$
Suppose we take $p=\frac{a}{b}$, then
$$(k+1)p+\frac{k}{p}=k.$$
This implies
$$(k+1)p^2-kp+k=0.$$
Solving for $p$, which is rational, we see that
$$p=\frac{k\pm\sqrt{k^2-4(k+1)k}}{2(k+1)}$$
For $p$ to be rational, we must have that the term inside square a perfect square. That is
$$-(3k^2+4k).$$ We need this to be positive. Hence $3k^2+4k$ must be negative or zero. Which happens only for $k=0$ or $k=-1$.
Now if $k=0$ or $k=-1$ we repeat the same argument done above to come to conclusion that the only invertible elements are
$$\{\pm 1, \pm x, \pm(1+x)\}.$$

Small remark, you wrote $\sqrt{k^2-4(k+1)k}$ has to be perfect square so $-3k^2-4k$ must be square, right?

Oh! Thanks for rectification. Even then, the argument and conclusion remain valid. I have edited the answer.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

Note  $,\pm(1+x) = \mp x^2,$ so your unit list is simply $,\pm x^i,\ \ i< 3.\ \ $

One can show that the this ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, where $\omega=exp(2\pi i/3)$ is a primitive 3rd root of unity. The inverse in $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$ is given by the Galois conjugate divided by the field norm $N(a+b\omega) = (a+b\omega)(a+b\omega^2) = a^2 +b^2 -ab$.
This element is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ if and only if $N(a+b\omega)=\pm{1}$.
To summarize, the invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(1+x+x^2)$ are precisely $\{a+bx:a^2 +b^2 -ab =\pm{1}\}$.
Edit: Thanks Yathi for the correction in the dimension of the quotient.

Any element of $R$ simply looks like $ax+b+(x^2+x+1)$ because of the division algorithm with monic polynomial $x^+x+1$.

Thanks @Yathi for the correction, I edited the answer.

For which integers $a$ and $b$, $a^2+b^2-ab $ would be $-1$?

To make it simpler to see when you have a unit, notice that $$4N(\alpha)=(2a-b)^2+3b^2$$ From this me must have $b=0, \pm 1$

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
